# Add shared library into Qt .pro file

Tags: c++, qt

I have shared library(.so file) and I want to add that file into Qt .pro file.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the LIBS variable as vahancho suggests:

```
LIBS += -lQtSolutions_SingleApplication-2.6
# and more:
unix:LIBS += -lQxtCore -lQxtWeb -lQxtNetwork -lQtSolutions_IOCompressor-2.3

CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    win32:LIBS += -lbfd -liberty -limagehlp
}
# and so on
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs